# How change a path value after init Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the next code.

It's works, but for example in another local of code when I try to change the path `"flightPath.strokeOpacity = 0"` dynamically doesn't show this change.

I would like know how to change dynamically a path. This function is started when I click on button.

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
    new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: You're defining `flightpath` locally to `initialize`. If you want to use that variable outside of that function you'll have to declare it globally instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use documented methods. to change the strokeOpacity, use .setOptions:

   flightPath.setOptions({strokeOpacity:0});
2. use variables in their defined scope.  To use a button click listener from HTML, it must be in the global scope. Or use google.maps.event.addDomListener in the scope in which it is defined.

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4d9yvoof/1/)

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
    new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('hide'), 'click', function() {
    flightPath.setOptions({
      strokeOpacity: 0
    });
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('show'), 'click', function() {
    flightPath.setOptions({
      strokeOpacity: 1.0
    });
  });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<input id="hide" type="button" value="hide" />
<input id="show" type="button" value="show" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change a Polyline property, you should re-assign the property using `.set()`

```
flightPath.set('strokeOpacity', '0');
```

but be aware that your variables must be visible outside the `initialize` scope:

```
(function() {
    var map;
    var flightPath;

    function initialize() {
       ...
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    // Sometime in the future...
    flightPath.set('strokeOpacity', '0');
})();
```